# how to dynamically add line break in iosMath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**the problem;**

I am using [iosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) library to display latex. Since the latex also includes text, it is too wide. iosMath does not handle (no line break or sth similar) and half of the text is invisible.

**Question 1**:  How can I display long latex is iosMath?

**one of the solutions** that I want to apply;

MTMathUILabel returns a UIView. I compare its frame with the device width and I want to manipulate the string according to this value. Let's simulate the case and my solution;

```
let latexString = "this is the equation: $$x^2 = 36$$. Could you solve this question for x?"
let pseudoLabel = MTMathUILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
pseudoLabel.latex = latexString
pseudoLabel.sizeToFit()

if pseudoLabel.frame.width > latexView.frame.width {
    let division = latexView.frame.width / expressionLabel.frame.width
    let divCount = Int(division.rounded(.up))
    let divisionRange = latexCharList / divCount
    for index in 0..<divCount {
        // latexCharList.insert("\\", at: index * divisionRange)
    }
    latexView.mathList = latexCharList
}
```

**latexCharList** stands for the latex conversion of the string. Then, I want to manipulate this list by adding a line break.
**latexView** is the view that I have in the storyboard.

I cannot complete this solution because I cannot get the number of latex and latex display array. This is the point that I am stuck for this solution.

**Question 2**: How can I manipulate the latex display by following the way in the example?

Why do not I change the string? Because latex presentation of the string has different length than the original string.

- this is neither ideal solution nor my first choice. However, this looks more efficient way for now. I am open for any other solutions (by using iosMath)

Comment: Hey did u get any proper solution for this?